# Redis key expire event through EXPIREAT command with past timestamp

Tags: redis, spring-data-redis

According to redis doc:

> EXPIREAT has the same effect and semantic as EXPIRE, but instead of
>   specifying the number of seconds representing the TTL (time to live),
>   it takes an absolute Unix timestamp (seconds since January 1, 1970). A
>   timestamp in the past will delete the key immediately.

While setting past timestamp, I'm getting exactly same behavior as per doc except there is no key expiry event thrown.

```
redis> SET mykey "Hello"
"OK"
redis> EXISTS mykey
(integer) 1
redis> EXPIREAT mykey 1293840000
(integer) 1
redis> EXISTS mykey
(integer) 0
```

It throws key expiry event upon key expire when I set future timestamp in `EXPIREAT` command.

So is it not supported to get key expiry event while setting past timestamp through `EXPIREAT`?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In your case, there's no expire event.

> So is it not supported to get key expiry event while setting past timestamp through EXPIREAT?

In fact, It depends.

If your Redis is loading data or it's a slave, Redis sets expiration for the given key, and publishes an *expire* event. Otherwise, Redis deletes or unlinks the given key, and publishes a *del* event.

So, in your case, you'll get a *del* event instead.